# Can I install two versions (1.4 and 1.6) of svnserve and configure it to run simultaneously on a single host?

Tags: svn, multiple-instances

We are looking to deploy two instances of subversion server to service two separate groups: one running subversion 1.4 and another subversion 1.6. I don't have much experience in installation/configuration of an svn server, so how should I do this?

If this is indeed possible, what do I need to know to get this running? Is it enough to simply install in two different directory paths and configure two services each pointing to a separate installation?

Comment: Do you have to use svnserve? It is also possible to serve SVN archives using WEBDAV on apache.

Answer (score 2):

You will also need to make sure that they are serving on different ports. This will mean at least 1 group using a non-standard port number.